# Continuing pattern matches to identify SQL clauses

Tags: regex, r

I am attempting to write a function in R that uses regular expressions to identify table names from SQL code.

I am using capturing groups to identify any words/alpha-num expressions that are found after **from** or **join**, but *if* my understanding is correct, capturing groups only allow the last captured group to be accessible.

```
##sample SQL code:
mySql <- 'select all from table1 join table2 join table3 join new_table3'

##regex:
gsub('.*(from|join)\\s*([[:alnum:]]+_*[[:alnum:]]+).*', '\\1 : \\2', mySql)

##result is only the last table in SQL code:
##"join : new_table3"
```

But what I want are all the table names to be returned, like so:

```
from : table1
join : table2
join : table3
join : new_table3
```

Or is this even a valid use of regex, as I think it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
cat(gsub('.*?(from|join)\\s+([[:alnum:]_]+)', '\\1 : \\2\n', mySql))
#from : table1
#join : table2
#join : table3
#join : new_table3
```

Answer (score 2):

You have make your pattern non-greedy by adding a `?` (greedy will try to eat as many characters as possible.. and thats why you are getting only last pattern):

```
.*?(from|join)\\s+([[:alnum:]]+_*[[:alnum:]]+)
  ↑
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aD2rI1/13)

Comment: karthik, thanks ever so much for adding the explanation too! I wish I could select both answers (your's and akrun's) but unfortunately can only select one...

Comment: It's okay.  Just wanted to correct it to avoid the OP getting errors

Comment: @info_seekeR No probs.. happy to help :)